# foreach alternative to speed up method

Tags: c#, linq

I'm stepping through this code and this method is taking awhile to iterate through 20K products.
Is there an alternative to the foreach loop to speed this up? Could this be done with Linq?

```
public IEnumerable<IProduct> ReturnOnlyRequestedSkus(IEnumerable<IProduct> products, IEnumerable<string> requestedSkus)
{
    var productList = new List<IProduct>();

    var allowedProducts = from sku in requestedSkus
                          join product in products
                          on sku.ToUpper() equals product.Sku.ToUpper()
                          select product;

    foreach (var product in allowedProducts)
    {
        if (product.ItemType.Equals("Kit", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) 
                 && product.KitIncludes != null)
        {
            var skusInKit = product.KitIncludes.Select(x => x.Sku);
            var skusInProducts = products.Select(x => x.Sku);

            if (skusInProducts.ContainsAll(skusInKit))
            {
                productList.Add(product);
            }

        }
    }

    return productList;
}
```

Comment: What do you think LINQ does under the hood?   Worrying about foreach vs LINQ is a red herring, look at other inefficiencies in your code

Comment: Could you provide more information? There isn't enough to tell us how best to help you/

Comment: Alternatively you can run your code in another thread and return the result by callback or event.

Comment: One thing that I think might be inefficient is the statement:
    `var skusInProducts = products.Select(x => x.Sku);`
It is done during every iteration of the loop, but it is not necessary because the `products` collection does not change. So, you could do it before the loop.

Comment: Typically anything done in LINQ is going to perform less, not better, if there is any significant change. LINQ is just sugar to simplify things.

Comment: Remember that `allowedProducts` is an object that doesn't actually contain the data but provides an interface for deferred execution of the query. Call `ToList()` on the resultset to force it all to execute. Then check to see if the performance issue is during the iterative loop as you believe or if it is actually a DB performance issue.

Comment: Replace `productList.Add` with `yield return product;` and get rid of all other `productList` references then it will _start_ returning items faster and consume less memory - but overall, no, LINQ per se will not make this faster. Look at the other places you are iterating repeatedly over enumerables like the `products` enumerable.

Comment: What are `products` and `requestedSkus`? Setup `skusInProducts` outside the loop as a `HashSet`.

Comment: Actually LINQ *could* make this faster if the entire query can be pushed to the database for execution. For example you only want kits so push that to the database as a WHERE on the query, don't fetch them all over the wire into memory.

Comment: Reusing the name product is so confusing

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you are actually trying to query a database here (you didn't say, but most applications handling 20K+ products tend not to hold them in memory), use `IQueryable` instead and turn it into one big LINQ expression and pass it to the database to evaluate instead of reading it all into memory for client-side querying and list building.

```
public IQueryable<IProduct> ReturnOnlyRequestedSkus(IQueryable<IProduct> 
products, IEnumerable<string> requestedSkus)
{
  return products
    .Where(p => requestedSkus.Any(sku => String.Equals(p.Sku, sku, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase &&
       p.ItemType.Equals("Kit", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && 
       p.KitIncludes != null &&
       ...
       ;
}
```

That way (i) you pass less across the wire; (ii) the database itself can optimize the query; (iii) your results are lazily evaluated so if someone calls `.First()` on them, or `.Count()` it isn't going to fetch them all.

BUT what's that last part checking? That all the parts in a kit are products themselves? Isn't that something you should be ensuring at the database level using a constraint?

Comment: Is there any indication from the OP that this is LINQ to SQL?  This could just be pure LINQ (since there are obvious inefficiencies)

Comment: @maccettura The question explicitly shows the parameters as `IEnumerable`, not `IQueryable`, so we actually know conclusively that this *isn't* some DB querying operation.

Comment: @Servy good point.  So this answer isn't applicable at all then

Comment: @maccettura, @servy Good point, it *should* be `IQueryable` - product catalogs don't normally live in memory - but we shouldn't assume that - I added a preface to the answer.